# cakephp - how to change pagination condition?

Tags: cakephp, controller, sql-order-by, cakephp-1.3

on several places in same controller i have code like:

```
$publications = $this->paginate('Publication', $conditions);
```

...where $conditions is array of conditions, which fields to select and how (using LIKE in mysql).

every one of them have different "Order by" statement.

how can i achieve that, and define different "order by" part of sql?

UPDATE (2011-03-11): this is part how i defined pagination:

```
$this->paginate = array(
        'limit' => 1, 
        'fields' => array('`Publication`.*, PublicationNumeration.*, Collection.*, Publisher.*, Publication.title as PublicationTitle'), 
        'joins' => array( array('table' => 'publication_numerations', 'alias' => 'PublicationNumeration', 'type' => 'LEFT', 'conditions' => array( 'Publication.id = PublicationNumeration.publication_id' ) ) ) 
        , 'order' => array('PublicationTitle desc')
      );

            $publications = $this->paginate('Publication', $conditions);
            $this->set(compact('publications', 'urlArgs'));
```

part with 'limit' works, but 'order' does not works, and does not show in debug mode at all.

Comment: Please post your `$conditions` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the pagination function for each time that you implement it in each different action. For example:

```
function list_recipes() {
    $this->paginate = array(
        'limit' => 10,
        'order' => array(
            'Recipe.title' => 'asc'
        )
    );
    $data = $this->paginate('Recipe');
    $this->set(compact('data'));
}
```

In your case, you'd probably want to reuse your `$conditions` array but alter the value of `'order'` for each different implementation.

Further Reference: [Pagination doc](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html)

Comment: tried that before, but it create lots of "Undefined index" error messages.

Comment: ok, so 'undefined index' error was my mistake, i had to add 'fields' part of paginate parameters. BUT, 'order' part does not works. part with 'limit' is there and it works, but i can not find 'order' in sql queries in debug block of the page... what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: in next post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671442/cakephp-order-in-hasmany-model-being-ignored is mentioned that 'models $order property only affects find calls'....... how can i solve my problem?

Comment: i manage to manage something with this problem, merging conditions array with some fake array like: $conditions = array_merge( $conditions, array(1=>'1 order by Publication.title DESC ') ); so, is this solution safe to have?

Comment: The $order property is in the model and shouldn't necessarily be something to worry about in your pagination function. Can you please post your entire $conditions array?

Answer (score 1):

I used this idea to create a custom selection of items per page.
My default pagination:

```
var $paginate = array( 'order' => array('User.id' => 'asc') );
```

I added this to my controller to change the limit to 25 (also added 1 for 5 and 10 just to see how it would go and changed the limit value accordingly):

```
function list25() {
//fetches with different limit than default

    $this->paginate = array(
        'limit' => 25,
        'order' => array(
            'User.id' => 'asc'
        )
    );
    $data = $this->paginate('User');
    $this->set('users', $data); 
}
```

Then, in my main view (index.ctp) I added this at the bottom of the data listing:

```
<span style="float:right;">
<?php echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style='vertical-align:top;font-size:12px;'>Show:</span>";
      echo $html->link(' 5', array('controller'=>'users', 'action' => 'list5'));
      echo $html->link(' 10', array('controller'=>'users', 'action' => 'list10'));
      echo $html->link(' 25', array('controller'=>'users', 'action' => 'list25'));
    ?>
</span>
<span style="float:right;margin-right:10px;"><?php  echo $paginator->numbers(); ?></span>
```

...which shows the following text at the bottom of the display:  *Show: 5 10 25*
The numbers, when clicked, are linked to the controller action and thus resets the limit (and refreshes the page with the new limit set).

Perhaps there is a better way to achieve the same functionality as I had to create a view for each option:  list5.ctp, list10.ctp and list25.ctp.  Anyway, it provides the user a chance to choose how much data they want to see on a page.  Comments?

....noob cakePHP user...

Comment: The fact that you have to create a view for each page makes this broken.  Really should be an indicator to you that either the idea is flawed or your implementation isn't complete.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
        echo $this->Paginator->link('5',array('limit' => '5'))
        echo $this->Paginator->link('10',array('limit' => '10'));
        echo $this->Paginator->link('10',array('limit' => '25'));